# Вложение изображений в сообщение

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как вложить изображение в сообщение?

Comment: Что получилось до сих пор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации всё чёрным по белому написано.
Метод message.send, параметр attachment.
Пример выглядит примерно так:
https://api.vk.com/method/message.send?user_id=****&attachment=photo***_***&v=5.52
user_id может быть заменён на peer_id, chat_id, user_ids(в зависимости от цели сообщения).
attachment - параметр медиавложения. Вид данного параметра: arrachment = _. Иносказательно:  - тип медиавложения(photo, video, audio, doc, wall, market),  - идентификатор владельца медиавложения,  - идентификатор медиавложения.